# How do I parse malformed Json in Java on Android?

Tags: java, android, json

So I have a Jsonobject which I get as a response from my server in the following format:

```
{"SubjectName":["Irish"],"BookName":["Bun Go Barr 1"]}{"WorksheetID":[5],"WorksheetName":["TESTS"]}
```

Usually to get the result I would simply do a basic loop through the particular array within the object in the following way:

```
try {
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("SubjectName");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BookSubject = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                BookSubject[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

however it seems that there is an extra "{" in this case seperating some of the arrays meaning when I try do that for a worksheetID I get the following in the logcat:

```
 03-12 08:21:02.019  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for WorksheetID
    03-12 08:21:02.019  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
    03-12 08:21:02.019  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:549)
    03-12 08:21:02.019  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at net.azurewebsites.cosy.Classroom.onCreate(Classroom.java:114)
    03-12 08:21:02.019  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    03-12 08:21:02.019  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    03-12 08:21:02.019  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    03-12 08:21:02.019  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    03-12 08:21:02.019  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    03-12 08:21:02.019  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    03-12 08:21:02.019  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    03-12 08:21:02.019  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    03-12 08:21:02.019  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    03-12 08:21:02.023  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-12 08:21:02.023  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    03-12 08:21:02.023  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    03-12 08:21:02.027  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    03-12 08:21:02.027  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-12 08:21:02.031  10836-10836/net.azurewebsites.cosy D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
```

Anyone know how I can get it to pick it up?

Comment: first get jsonObject from response and then get json Array from it

Comment: Are you in control of what sends the json?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Try linting your JSON in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Hence, my question... @kkaosninja Cool link!

Comment: @BuvinJ I am in control. Basically I am doing two seperate SQL queries and I and I am trying to return the response as one object.

Comment: then your parsing is wrong. You should do it as I suggested above. And also your json is not proper. Either wrap entire json in to an array or object

Comment: See the answer by @kkaosninja then.  Send valid json to parse, rather than fixing it on the client end.

Answer (score 2):

Your json is invalid .

You can test json online tools http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Change form :

```
{"SubjectName":["Irish"],"BookName":["Bun Go Barr 1"]}{"WorksheetID":[5],"WorksheetName":["TESTS"]}
```

To :

```
[
  {
    "SubjectName": "Irish",
    "BookName": "Bun Go Barr 1"
  },
  {
    "WorksheetID": 5,
    "WorksheetName": "TESTS"
  }
]
```

Comment: @ahmadaghazadeh I am getting this as a response I can't simply reformat it like this.

Comment: @EoinÓCribín get your response changed. It is not in proper format

Comment: @EoinÓCribín of course you can. It's bloody string. Do some string search & replaces and make it valid json